# How do I use XDT transforms with my own XML file?

Tags: xml, msbuild, xdt-transform, xdt

How to I tell my MSBuild (probably in my project file) that I want to use XDT transforms on my own XML file? I have the standard Web.config and Web.Release.config which Visual Studio shows as a dependent file of Web.config. I also have foo.config and foo.Release.config.

1. The Release version is not displaying as dependent on foo.config. It is just displaying as a normal content file.
2. More importantly, the transform doesn't happen on build. No errors - it just isn't even trying to merge the files.

I assume the two issues are related. If I get them configured correctly, the transforms will just work as expected.

If it matters, I am using VS2013.

Comment: It's not made for that but there is [SlowCheetah - XML Transforms 
This package enables you to transform your app.config or any other XML file based on the build configuration](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/69023d00-a4f9-4a34-a6cd-7e854ba318b5).

Comment: My understanding was that SlowCheetah is exactly what was built into VS 2013. Is that not correct?

Comment: It appears the author would like Microsoft to do that for VS 2014. See [here](http://sedodream.com/CategoryView,category,SlowCheetah.aspx).

Comment: Oh, I see. Thanks very much. If you post your first comment as an answer, I'll mark it correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not made for that but there is [SlowCheetah - XML Transforms This package enables you to transform your app.config or any other XML file based on the build configuration](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/69023d00-a4f9-4a34-a6cd-7e854ba318b5).

It appears the author has wanted Microsoft to incorporate into Visual Studio. He's not going to add support for VS 2014. See [here](http://sedodream.com/CategoryView,category,SlowCheetah.aspx).